# Minha aplicação esta continunado sem valores recebidos JS

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber o por que da minha aplicação esta continuando sem receber nenhum valor, a minha intenção é que ela só continue após receber os valores requisitados.

```js
 
const nome = prompt('Qual é o seu nome?')
if(nome.length == 0) {
  alert('digite um nome')
}
const idade = prompt('qual é a sua idade?')
const linguagem = prompt('Qual linguagem de programação você está estudando?')
          
alert(`Você se chama: ${nome}, você tem ${idade} de idade, sua linguagem favorita é: ${linguagem}`);
```

Comment: *"que ela só continue após receber os valores requisitados."* e não faltou parar o código? do jeito que está mostra a mensagem e continua.. se esse código estiver numa função falta ai um `return`

Comment: Acredito que para o que você está querendo terá que trabalhar com [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp), com uma lógica do tipo: enquanto estiver vazio pergunte novamente. Mas lembre que a sua tela ficará trancada com isso. Uma outra opção seria se um dos campos ficar em branco informar: Dados incompletos.

Comment: Como posso parar o código pra ele só continuar após receber os dados? já tentei break e não consegui.

Comment: Boa tarde! Neste caso você precisa validar as entradas. Construir estruturas condicionais no seu código para permitir o avanço do fluxo somente se o usuário preencher o valor solicitado no prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um loop do-while para pedir pelo nome do usuário enquanto ele não digitar um nome válido:

```js
let nome = "";
do{
    nome = prompt("Qual seu nome?")
}while(nome.length === 0);
console.log(nome); //Aqui o nome estará preenchido.
```

Esse loop fará com que o prompt continue sendo mostrado enquanto o usuário não digitar um nome válido (com pelo menos um caractere).

A partir daí você pode repetir a mesma lógica para a idade e para a linguagem de programação. No final, você terá as três informações.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!